# How to handle a release event for the second finger in QOpenGLWindow

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to create an Android game controller to make a Super Mario clone, just to learn programming and practice:

[image]

The next problem stopped me. I touch the screen with my first finger. While holding the first finger, I touch and release the second finger. I expect that when I release the second finger, the Qt Creator debug console should display:

```
TouchUpdate  2
TouchUpdate  1
```

```cpp
void OpenGLWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        {
            qDebug() << "TouchBegin";
            event->accept();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        {
            qDebug() << "TouchUpdate " << event->points().length();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But only the first few releases work normally. Then the releases work with delays. And after a few more releases I see:

```
TouchUpdate  2
TouchUpdate  2
```

Minimal example: [release-event-of-the-second-finger-qt6-cpp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3vgs0gw0sfg3a1ptbgt7h/release-event-of-the-second-finger-qt6-cpp.zip?rlkey=wpzc7xx3oxk32dewpcw6beo7a&dl=1)

Comment: Did you check the `state()` of each touch point?

Comment: You're welcome, but, please, **do** study the documentation. I've never even used touch events, and yet it took me less than a minute to find out about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qeventpoint.html#State-enum

```cpp
void OpenGLWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        {
            qDebug() << "TouchBegin";
            event->accept();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        {
            if (event->points().length() > 1)
            {
                QEventPoint::State firstState = event->points()[0].state();
                QEventPoint::State secondState = event->points()[1].state();
                if (firstState == QEventPoint::State::Released ||
                    secondState == QEventPoint::State::Released)
                {
                    qDebug() << "Released";
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the example above. It works with Box2D on Android:

[image]